# How to retain html values on returning with results from servlet

Tags: forms, jsp, servlets

I have a jsp page with 2 textboxes and a submit button and on submitting i get the work done by a servlet based on the textbox values and displays the result retrieved from db in the same jsp page in html table format.

I want to achieve the following:

1. how to retain the same values in the text box? For example, I select march 3rd (`txtbox1`) to apr 4th (`txbox2`). After it returns after submission it should show the same march 3rd and apr 4th in the textboxes.
2. First time when i reach that page i want the current date to be displayed in those text boxes.
3. How can i extract the html table data (which i get after submission) as it is in excel and pdf files on button clicks?

Comment: couldn't understand your 3rd question. you want to extract html data from excel??

Comment: the table that displays on the page with the data ..i want that be downloaded as a excel file on a button click and another button shud download it as a pdf file.

Comment: there are hundreds of links that show up when you google for "html to excel/pdf"

Answer (score 0):

Here are my thoughts.

> 1) how to retain the same values in the text box? For example, I select march 3rd (txtbox1) to apr 4th (txbox2). After it returns after
>   submission it should show the same march 3rd and apr 4th in the
>   textboxes.

To retain values in a textbox after back button is clicked or when page is refreshed:

1. Have the same servlet present the form, process the data, and present the results.
2. Have one servlet present the form; have a second servlet process the data and present the results. The transferring of variables from one servlet to another could be done using response.SendRedirect or RequestDispatcher.forward() or as HttpSession attributes.
3. Have a JSP page “manually” present the form; have a servlet or JSP page process the data and present the results.
4. Have a JSP page present the form, automatically filling in the fields with values obtained from a data object. Have a servlet or JSP page process the data and present the results. To achieve this we need to use JSTL and Struts.

> 2) First time when i reach that page i want the current date to be displayed in those text boxes.

Using JSTL,

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<jsp:useBean id="now" class="java.util.Date" scope="request" />
<fmt:formatDate value="${now}" pattern="MM.dd.yyyy" />
```

or Using Scriptlets,

```
<%@page import="java.util.Date"%>

        <%
            Date d = new Date();
        %>
       <%=d.toString()%>
```

> 3)How can i extract the html table data (which i get after submission)
>   as it is in excel and pdf files on button clicks?

[What is the best way to convert HTML into Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974798/what-is-the-best-way-to-convert-html-into-excel)
and
[Html to PDF](http://pdfcrowd.com/)